# Prevent Memory Corruption During Writes with Power Loss

Tags: embedded, memory-corruption

I have a system that runs windows via a USB stick (it's a proprietary machine). This type of machine is commonly powered off by 'pulling the plug'. There is no way around it, that is how it is operated.

We occasionally have drive corruption on the USB stick, or at least corruption in the directory that we write things into. Is there really any software solution to get around this problem other than 'write as little/infrequently as possible'?

It's a windows machine and the applications that write are typically written in Java/C# if that is useful to anyone. The corruption typically shows up as a write directory or the parent of a write directory that can no longer be accessed due to the corruption. The only way to deal with it is to delete it via command line and start over.

Is there any way to programmatically deal with such a scenario, to perhaps restore a previous state of the memory as opposed to deleting and starting anew?

Comment: First off, this isn't really a programming question.  It's probably better suited for a place like SuperUser instead.  That said, my second point is a little more direct - if you interrupt a device, running "any program" then the loss of power and its ability to finish will be at the mercy of the specific program/OS operation in flux during the loss of power.  It's that simple.  This is why we have well-defined processes such as UPC power backups and proper shutdown procedures.

Comment: I was looking for more of a programmatic coping mechanism. Perhaps 'restore' it from a corrupted partial-write state.

Comment: Unless you can pinpoint precisely *how* the corruption will occur ahead of time, you cannot programmatically handle such corruption.  Again, that's why we have power backups and proper shutdown procedures.

Comment: Best guess would be a partial write that is causing it.- I understand what you are saying, though those kinds of options are not possible in this situation.

Comment: You can't, just, perform a controlled shut down of the process before turning off the machine?

Comment: No this pc is mounted to a larger, mobile machine (underground miner). The miner is shut off at the end of the shift. When the miner is shut off, all power is lost to the mounted devices. It's not an option to modify the miner.

Comment: If you can't modify it, what kind of programmatic solution were you considering?  It sounds like you couldn't apply the software change anyway.  Further, it sounds like you're just going to have to put up with corrupted files, if this is how poorly designed this system is.

Comment: @Tacitus86 - This is poor design and planning, no qualms about it.  Stop "yanking the power," as you're also going to potentially damage hardware, let alone lose data and experience memory corruption.  **Do a proper shutdown process** or be at the mercy of "the unknown," unfortunately.

Comment: @Amy I'm free to modify the software but that's about it. It's a small portion of the whole of the device. A programmatic solution in my mind would be able to store memory states and then restore it if a corruption is detected.

Comment: That isn't going to be effective.

Comment: What you could do (even if that does not completely solve the problem)  is write to alternate devices/files. That way you might be left at least with the last file version *before* the crash.

Comment: Yeah that or move the previous ones to another place before writing the new one.

Comment: What filesystem are you using on the USB stick?

Comment: @Nate It uses NTFS. Also it contains an installation of Win 7 Embedded.

Comment: I was under the impression NTFS was robust against power loss as it is a journaling file system. Are there any options in the windows 7 embedded that can be changed to select between reliability and performance of the filesystem?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I know many USB sticks themselves are targeted towards performance or reliability and we stick to ones that are highly related towards reliability. This issue isn't extremely common but it does occur occasionally. We are trying to remedy that 'occasional' instance.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue in a lab? It may be that protocol over USB is not reliable compared to SATA or SCSI.

Comment: Oh man, do I wish we could reproduce it. We have tried COUNTLESS times of pulling the plug but haven't been able to. It has only happened a handful of times in countless hours of operation at site among dozens of devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel as though there is any way to prevent this type of thing from happening given our current design. If you do enough writes and keep pulling the plug you are eventually going to get a corruption and that's just facts. Especially in this design. Even if the backup batteries are charged, if the software doesn't shutdown gracefully within the battery's discharge time, the corruptions could still occur. Not to mention as gravitymixes said above its going to damage hardware eventually which we have seen before.

A system redesign needs to considered for this project as a whole. Some type of networked solution comes to mind immediately where data is sent off the volatile machine to be logged on a machine with a more reliable power source over a reliable network connection with writing to the disk on the actual volatile machine as a last ditch effort if network comms are not reliable at a given point in time (backfill). I feel like this would increase hardware life as well. Of course the problem of network reliability then becomes your problem.

Comment: Most database servers are designed to be robust against power loss. In my company we perform power cycle tests specifically to validate that our embedded boxes don't lose there config file under these conditions.